# Why does applying a TimeSpan format inSSRS give Error SOMETIMES

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, timespan

1. No, there are no NULLs involved
2. Removing the Format string shows the TimeSpan using the default "c" format, so it is a definitely a TimeSpan object.

So, I have a report.  The report contains a chart, and a Tablix list.
For the "Value" in the data source I have a TimeSpan.

In the chart, the Value is "=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(Fields!Value.Value)))"
  The Vertical Axis Property Number is set to "Custom" "HH:mm:ss"

Both the Vertical Axis, and the Data Labels show (for example) 00:07:13

I also have a Tablix, with a column that has at the Group and Total levels, a cell with "=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(Fields!Value.Value)))"

With Number set to "Default", they both show (for example) 00:07:13.1234567, which is the "ToString" default.

If I set Number to "Custom" "HH:mm:ss", or to "Time", or I set the cell to "=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(Fields!Value.Value))).ToString("HH:mm:ss")", or "=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Avg(Fields!Value.Value))).ToString("HH:mm:ss")", it renders as "#Error"

Any suggestions as to what's wrong here?

EDIT:  hh\:mm\:ss works (lowercase H)

Answer (score 0):

And it seems the answer is that the Chart will "somehow" allow a TimeSpan to understand the formatting specifiers for DateTime, where a Tablix formatter does not.

So, the Chart will treat HH:mm:ss as the same as "hh\:mm\:ss", where only the latter is a valid format for TimeSpan.